# Where do you go when you die?

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness, character-death, soul

Following in the line of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49450/the-curse-of-sutekh-and-kinfolk), I know quite a bit about V:TM, W:TA, M:TA, and Mummy, but sadly I have almost no knowledge of the rest.

**What happens to the spirit/soul of oWOD creatures (including humans) when they die?**

What I understand so far:

- For vampires, it's a simple "game over." (Though I've seen some discussions that they do have souls, so they could continue the journey somewhere.)
- Mummies will resurrect after a while, after spending some time with Apophis.
- Shapeshifters as I understand have their own "paradise for heroes" (Legendary realm, if my memory is right) and in some cases they can guide or even reincarnate in their offspring (Ancestors/Pure Breed traits).
- Mages die as humans do, but theirs Avatar might reincarnate with another mage

What about the rest?

Answer (score 13):

Most of the rest of the World of Darkness creatures are in some respects or other human beings, and the deaths of humans, as described in **Wraith: the Oblivion**, leads to nonexistence, either through transcendence or oblivion. Those who have reasons or will enough to keep existing after that may become wraiths — see the aforementioned WtO — or otherwise remain as denizens of the Shadowlands.

Mages die as people do, although their Avatar shards return to the cycle and become attached to new humans with the possibility of awakening.

When it comes to changelings, the **Sluagh** book puts forward a theory that the Faerie soul reincarnates through the Changeling Way, reforming time after time in different kiths until, finally, one ends up as a sluagh in one's last lifetime. This is thought to be the result of unreliable narration, as it's not backed up in other books.

Answer (score 9):

In no particular order, this is what happens when a *splat dies in WoD.

The following creatures simply cease to exist, or in rare circumstances become a Wraith (see *Wraith: the Oblivion* for when a mortal becomes a wraith).

- Ghouls
- Revnants
- Dhampirs
- Garou Kinfolk
- Sorcerers
- Mediums
- Psychics
- Kinain
- Gypsies
- Thralls
- All other Mortals
- Vampires
- Imbued

We do have some special cases to deal with.

- Mages - Like any other mortal, their conscience soul ceases to exist (or become a wraith), their avatars are recycled and bound to a new mortal.
- Garou/Fera - 'Legendary Realm' (likely a layer under the Shadowlands)
- Changeling - reincarnate (most) or cease to exist (High Sidhe and in the Dreaming)

  - unless it was a Selkie, who are special.
- Wraith - Cease to exist/[eternity as an ashtray](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Samuel_Haight)
- Kuei-jin - Return to Yomi (where they are very similar or identical to Wraiths). They may attempt to take another Second Breath from Yomi.
- Risen - Do not technically die, as they were already dead.  The Wraith returns to the Shadowlands.
- Mummy - Spends time in the Shadowlands before returning to a mortal body.
- Demons - Body dies, the demon finds a new body, or descends to the Abyss.

Comment: Garou/Fera don't simply die, since they can be accessed by their offspring with "ancestors" trait and in the Legendary Realm you can talk with long-dead heroes. Also I really doubt they can be wraiths, since they technically never been humans for a start.

Comment: The underworld of Africa is filled with the now-sentient spirits of animals.  I am using the present-tense, but little is known about the condition of the underworld after 6GM.  But it suffices to say - humanity is not a prerequisite to become a ghost.

Comment: Kindred can also become wraiths. It is even rarer than in humans, but there is even an official character: Ignatius the Ur-Kindred from **Necropolis: Atlanta** (page 122). They cannot become wraiths if they are diablerized or they were in Golconda.

Comment: There are situations though where there is no going to possible at all as the soul is getting destroyed through death: Diablery by vampires, Souleating for demons/earthbound (they can eat souls of other demons and some earthbounds can eat souls of even humans). Not sure if other splats have similar powers that keep someone from becoming a wraith (or going to the abyss)

Comment: This is very true.  I only list that a character can become a wraith if there is the slightest possibility that they could, without context.

Comment: Where is it stated that vampires can become wraiths? (never read about it so far)

Comment: Kuei-jin are returned to Yomi, from whence they may take another Second Breath.

Comment: @FluxIX its a community wiki, feel free to add that

Comment: @ThomasE. The Harbingers of Skulls are believed to be deceased Cappadocian Cainites. Even though they went to the Shadowlands they managed to amass enough power (partially through their Mortis Discipline) to be able to affect the Skinlands and sometimes cross into the Skinlands.

Comment: I have read in M20 that Mages that die go to their believed place, if they believe in god they go to heaven, if they believe in roman deities they go to Elysium or underworld, if they believe in rebirth they go back into the circle.

Comment: The Legendary Realms aren’t attached to the Underworld; they’re in the Middle Umbra, adjacent to the Realm of Dreams. It’s where the characters from fictional stories in the mortal world live until they get enough mental energy invested into them to become god-forms and move into the High Umbra instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just to supplement for the Changelings: the individual *Changeling*, as in, the combination of fae soul A and mortal human B does die, yes, but as for what happens to the fae souls:

- Those fae who are regular Changelings reincarnate in a different mortal. (Though the soul could be lost if the Changeling died somewhere in the Dreaming off the Silver Path.) Since usually not all memories are kept, and either way there is a new human part of the soul coming up, while the core of the fae does remain the same, the new Changeling will be a somewhat different person. However, beyond the weird Sluagh theory mentioned above, there is no mention of changing Kith when reincarnating that I know of. I.e., once a Troll, always a Troll.
- The majority of the Sidhe, i.e. everyone who didn't adopt the Changeling Way back in the Renaissance, but retreated to Arcadia instead, do *not* reincarnate. Their souls fly out in a blaze of glory - where to, nobody knows, but presumably back to Arcadia.

I honestly don't know whether the *human* part of the dead Changeling could stay on as a Wraith oblivious to its previous Changeling existence, i.e. with memories only of the human part of its life. I presume it's theoretically possible, but highly unlikely. (Any proof of this or otherwise would be welcome!)

Hope this helps! If any of this was changed in C20, I'd be happy to find out, I'm still running the old versions, with only occasional introductions from the 20s.

Comment: And Selkies are... different again. Their skin can empower another Selkie-descendent